# Anguar2 Route provide template for Component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-components

Is there any way that I can specify the template to be wired up to a component in a route in Angular 2?

I have a component where the controller functionality is identical over three views. What I'd like to do is have three addresses with the same component but with three different html files. Ideally, I'd provide a `templateUrl` or `template: require(...` type syntax in the route which would provide the template file to the Component.

Comment: Use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` to display different parts of the same component.  You loose offline template compilation advantage if you build components dynamically at runtime.

Comment: That's a shame. I'm happy to register the templates at compile time, but want to select which is used in the route. I don't really want to have a massive html file with all three views in.

Comment: I've just used an injectable service that does the actual work into the component and then written a couple of properties and a method that simply pass the values through to the service. It's not perfect but the best I could come up with.

Comment: Sounds fine . . . ..  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, the best way that I could find to do this was to move the functionality out to an Injectable and inject that into separate Components which simply mapped the model interaction through to the back.

This works fine and my functionality code is only written once but I do have three (admittedly very slim) identical classes which is a shame.